# Ruby: How to escape backslash (`\`) to generate a command in ruby?

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a hash in ruby like below:

```rb
{"metric"=>"Mean F-Score",
 "columns"=>
  [{"name"=>"Id",
    "type"=>"String"},
   {"name"=>"Expected",
    "type"=>"String"}],
 "files"=>
  {"expected"=>"actual_output.csv"},
 "submission_filename"=>"/a/aa/submission.csv"}
```

The json for this hash is

```rb
irb(main):101:0> json_string = JSON.generate(a)
=> "{\"metric\":\"Mean F-Score\",\"columns\":[{\"name\":\"Id\",\"type\":\"String\"},{\"name\":\"Expected\",\"type\":\"String\"}],\"files\":{\"expected\":\"actual_output.csv\"},\"submission_filename\":\"/a/aa/submission.csv\"}"
```

I want to generate a bash command which can generate a json file using this json string:

I tried

```rb
irb(main):104:0> "echo \"#{json_string}\" > data.json"
=> "echo \"{\"metric\":\"Mean F-Score\",\"columns\":[{\"name\":\"Id\",\"type\":\"String\"},{\"name\":\"Expected\",\"type\":\"String\"}],\"files\":{\"expected\":\"actual_output.csv\"},\"submission_filename\":\"/a/aa/submission.csv\"}\" > data.json"
```

But on running this command on bash it is generating wrong json file.

I am trying to learn ruby and want to generate command (to run on different servers) like this, but was unable to escape the backslash:

```bash
echo "{\"metric\":\"Mean F-Score\",\"columns\":[{\"name\":\"Id\",\"type\":\"String\"},{\"name\":\"Expected\",\"type\":\"String\"}],\"files\":{\"expected\":\"actual_output.csv\"},\"submission_filename\":\"/a/aa/submission.csv\"}" > data.json
```

Comment: Why do you need to pass a JSON string to a bash command? You can just write it to a file  in Ruby.

Comment: Yes, I can create a file, but that file will not be accessible in different servers. So, I want to create a JSON file from the command so that the command will be the same across multiple servers. I can only run commands in servers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do 2 things to make this work

1. Wrap the `echo` parameters in single quotes to include double quotes in the output.
2. Use some ruby method to print the string to console like `puts` or `print` (otherwise ruby will print a string to the console with double quotes escaped like `\"`)

```rb
puts "echo '#{json_string}' > data.json"
```

This should output something like the below which you can run on the terminal to generate a JSON file.

```
echo '{"metric":"Mean F-Score","columns":[{"name":"Id","type":"String"},{"name":"Expected","type":"String"}],"files":{"expected":"actual_output.csv"},"submission_filename":"/a/aa/submission.csv"}' > data.json
 => nil
```

Comment: Yes, `puts `output the correct command in std:out, but I want to store the command in string.

Comment: @sankalp if you want to store it in a string just do something like `str = "echo '#{json_string}' > data.json"`

Comment: Yes, I tried this also, but the generated JSON file is invalid due to the presence of `\` in file.

Comment: @sankalp can you please share how you want the output file to look? An example would be great because I think I didn't fully understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```rb
`echo "#{json_string}" > data.json`
```

This executes a shell command from your irb-console. Found in https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Kernel.html#method-i-60

Comment: I don't want to run the command in the irb console.